# How to select p tags without class attributes in Selectolax

Tags: python, css-selectors

I am trying to select some p tags without class attributes using Selectolax without success.  This is my code:

```
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

tree = HTMLParser(
    '''
    <p class="card_street">
        <span class="card_street">123 My Rd. </span>
        <span class="card_street">Suite 100</span>
        <span> Anywhere</span>
        <span>, TX</span>
        <span> 12345</span>
    </p>
    '''
)

tree.css('p[class="card_street"] span:not([class]):nth-child(1)')
```

which gives:

```
[]
```

However, `tree.css('p[class="card_street"] span:not([class])')` is selecting the three span tags without a class attribute:

```
for node in tree.css('p[class="card_street"] > span:not([class])'):
    print(node.text())
```

gives:

```
 Anawhere
, TX
 12345
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to select the the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd span tags without class attributes?

Comment: Maybe someone else knows better, but I don't believe you can do that with pure css selectors. You'll have to use something like beautifulsoup.